# Query to get table name by searching data in SQL Server 20008

Tags: sql-server

Please, if anyone know, then provide me query to get the table name and DB name by searching data in complete database..

Comment: It would seem that English is not your first language. To assist people in understanding your problem, you may want to provide samples of the problem as well as desired outputs. No one will be rushing to answer a poorly constructed question.

Comment: If possible, try RedGate SQL search to make it easier. Also, search google. Is this what you want - find table in sql server

Comment: Please, try to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/04/29/sql-server-find-table-in-every-database-of-sql-server/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about providing a complete solution, rather than helping the question asker create a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for a table name in a **single** database like follows:

```
USE YourDatabaseName

SELECT *
FROM sys.Tables
WHERE name LIKE '%SearchText%'
```

You can also search for a table name in **all** databases like Pinal Dave describes [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/04/29/sql-server-find-table-in-every-database-of-sql-server/):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_FindTableNameInAllDatabase
    @TableName VARCHAR(256)
AS

DECLARE @DBName VARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @varSQL VARCHAR(512)
DECLARE @getDBName CURSOR

SET @getDBName = CURSOR FOR
SELECT name
FROM sys.databases
CREATE TABLE #TmpTable (DBName VARCHAR(256),
SchemaName VARCHAR(256),
TableName VARCHAR(256))

OPEN @getDBName
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getDBName INTO @DBName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @varSQL = 'USE ' + @DBName + ';
    INSERT INTO #TmpTable
    SELECT '''+ @DBName + ''' AS DBName,
    SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS SchemaName,
    name AS TableName
    FROM sys.tables
    WHERE name LIKE ''%' + @TableName + '%'''
    EXEC (@varSQL)
    FETCH NEXT
    FROM @getDBName INTO @DBName
END
CLOSE @getDBName
DEALLOCATE @getDBName

SELECT *
FROM #TmpTable
DROP TABLE #TmpTable
GO

EXEC usp_FindTableNameInAllDatabase 'Address'
GO
```